# How to select all objects that aren't in a manytomany relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I have the following models (resumed) in an application:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    plans = models.ManyToManyField('Plan')
    extra_services = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    services = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Plan here is just an aggregation of services, but an account may have separate services. In admin (Account) **I want to show a select box with all Services (extra_services) that AREN'T TIED with any Plan.** What's the best queryset I can use to get this (in limit_choices_to)?

PS: I don't want to iterate over all Plans to get all the Services ids that are linked and after that exclude them in a filter.

Answer (score 4):

`Service.objects.filter(plan_set__isnull=True)` should do.

You may find further explanation in [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Are you sure? I had already tried this, but with no luck (always get something like: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'plan_set'). I can do this in the oposite way: Plan.objects.filter(services__isnull=True).

Comment: I don't remember exactly right now, but you may always provide the `related_name` in your `Plan` model, e.g. `services = models.ManyToManyField('Service', related_name='plans')` and then query services using `Service.objects.filter(plans__isnull=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got this using a raw SQL query:

```
services = Service.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM accounts_service WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT service_id FROM accounts_plan_services);')
```

Anyway, can I do this without a raw SQL query?